# Generic WCF host

Tags: c#, wcf, hosting

I am thinking of coding a generic WCF host that can be configured and can handle errors like faulted state and crashes.

Do you know of some open source or example for me to begin?

**ADD**
Yes, i familiar with both of suggestions, im looking for the ServiseHost wrapper it self.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CodeProject code [here looks like similar to what](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/GenericWcfServiceHostAndC.aspx) you are looking for. At least, it should provide a good stating point.

Comment: i needed a bit more but this is good work i have seen it and added the disposed method in the right way

Answer (score 1):

There is a really cool project on CodePlex that is related to a generic hosting service that already includes declarative service registration and service isolation among other things. You can check it here:

http://wcfhosting.codeplex.com/